# refactor this function to reduce its cognitive complexity -sonarcloud error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can I please get some help on the below code block to reduce the complexity and split so it will reduce the size of the file and it is more accessible.

i am new to react and if i can get some help in how to do that would be really appreciated.

the error is produced from sonarcloud

```
import { validEmail } from '.';

export default (fieldName, rules, value, type, required) => {
    const frontError = [];
    if ('match' in rules && value !== rules.match) {
        frontError.push(`Does not match`);
      }

      if (required && (!value || (!value.length && !value.value))) {
        frontError.push(`Please provide ${startCase(fieldName)}`);
      } else if (rules.min && value.length < rules.min) {
        frontError.push(`Please provide a longer ${startCase(fieldName)} - minimum length is ${rules.min}`);
      }

      if (rules.lower && !/[a-z]/.test(value)) {
        frontError.push(`Must contain 1 or more lowercase letter`);
      }

      if (rules.upper && !/[A-Z]/.test(value)) {
        frontError.push(`Must contain 1 or more uppercase letter`);
      }

      if (rules.digit && !/\d/.test(value)) {
        frontError.push(`Must contain 1 or more digit`);
      }

      if (rules.special && !/[ `!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?~]/.test(value)) {
        frontError.push(`Must contain 1 or more special character`);
      }

      if (type === 'email' && !validEmail(value)) {
        frontError.push(`Please enter a valid email`);
      }

      if (frontError.length) {
          return frontError.join(' ');
      }

      return '';
};
```

Comment: There are maybe a few small improvements, but nothing significant that I can see. If I were you, I'd keep what you have if possible, it's possibly the most readable option. Refactoring might not help, despite satisfying the linter.

Comment: This question was asked yesterday. I can't locate it, but it ultimately was unresolved because the function/conditionals really couldn't be simplified.